# Convert month and year columns to a date column with additional string concatination

Tags: sql, sql-server

My TB1

```
MONTH    YEAR 
-----    ----
2        2015
```

How to Convert month and year columns to a date column with additional string concatenation :-

```
M_DELIVERY            Description
----------           -------------
FEB-15              DELIVERY FOR FEB 2015
```

Comment: Lack of sample data and details.

Comment: Can you perhaps stop abusing formatting and ALL CAPS? This doesn't get you better or faster answers to your questions. Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your are using date and MSSQL2012+:

```
SELECT  UPPER( FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-01',121),'MMM')) + '-' +RIGHT(CAST( YEAR( CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-01',121)) AS VARCHAR(4)),2) M_DELIVERY
, 'DELIVERY FOR ' +UPPER( FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-01',121),'MMM'))+' '+ CAST( YEAR( CONVERT(datetime, '2017-02-01',121)) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Description
```

Other way(using numbers and not date):
(you can change months name abbrev.)

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING('GENFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC',1+(MONTH_NUMB-1)*3,3)+'-'+ RIGHT(YEAR_NUMB,2) AS M_DELIVERY
    , 'DELIVERY FOR ' + SUBSTRING('GENFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC',1+(MONTH_NUMB-1)*3,3)+' '+ CAST(YEAR_NUMB AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DESCRIPTION
    FROM /* sample data */ (SELECT 2 AS MONTH_NUMB, 2015 AS YEAR_NUMB
          UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH_NUMB, 2017 AS YEAR_NUMB
          UNION SELECT 1 AS MONTH_NUMB, 2016 AS YEAR_NUMB) X
```

Output for the latter:

```
M_DELIVERY DESCRIPTION
---------- ---------------------
GEN-16     DELIVERY FOR GEN 2016
FEB-15     DELIVERY FOR FEB 2015
DIC-17     DELIVERY FOR DEC 2017
```

Comment: Just to mention: `FORMAT` needs SQL Server 2012+. And furthermore the OP does not use a `DATETIME` but separate `INT`s for year and month... Your approach would bloat quite a bit, if you'd create a date in all places needed...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very "thin"... For your next question please read [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

For this you can try it like here:

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(TheMonth INT,TheYear INT);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES(2,2015),(5,2017);

SELECT d.TheMonth
      ,d.TheYear
      ,A.AsDateTime
      ,UPPER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),A.AsDateTime,100)) + '-' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),A.AsDateTime,101),2) AS ShortString
      ,'DELIVERY FOR ' + UPPER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),A.AsDateTime,100)) + ' ' + CAST(d.TheYear AS VARCHAR(4)) AS LongString
FROM @Dummy AS d
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(CAST(d.TheYear AS VARCHAR(4)) + REPLACE(STR(d.TheMonth,2),' ','0')+'01' AS DATETIME)) AS A(AsDateTime);
```

Returns

```
M   Y       AsDateTime              ShortString LongString
2   2015    2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 FEB-15      DELIVERY FOR FEB 2015
5   2017    2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 MAI-17      DELIVERY FOR MAI 2017
```

You did not provide your SQL Server's version. Starting with 2012 you might get this easier with `FORMAT` and `CONCAT`

### Hint: Beware of culture/language settings!

As you can see, my system produced "Mai" which is german spelling of "May". Culture dependant formats (and even worse: language dependant formats) are something very dangerous...